# Can't fetch parse file from PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfobject, pffile

Trying to fetch a PFfile from PfObject but when I fetch value of a particular key , it only gives me a class name

Here is my CloudCode

```
Parse.Cloud.define("fetchBusinessWithID", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Business");
  query.equalTo("uniqueBusinessID", request.params.businessId);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      if(results.length > 0)
         {
         var fetchedObject = results[0];

         response.success(fetchedObject);
    }
    else
    {

         response.error("No Business Saved Yet");
    }



    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("Something Went wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

And this is on iOS

```
PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"fetchBusinessWithID"
                       withParameters:@{@"businessId": @"Madept2"}
                                block:^( PFObject *business, NSError *error) {

                                }];
```

When I see PFObject in Debug console[image]

So how can I fetch attributes of this file, as I can not parse full object of PfFile, Please help me on this, What I am doing wrong.

Here is my data Model

[image]

Comment: So your business class has a reference to yhe PFFile? Stored in the aboutImage key? Have you written any code to use the file (download it)?

Comment: I will download that ,once i get image url, But i can't get any property of PFFIle Object

Comment: the PFFile is the image data, it doesn't provide a URL to the image data. the file itself has a URL but you generally use the PFFile API to get the data

Comment: @Wain But I should atleast have a PFfile Object to call any Api, How will I download data unless I am not having any PFfile instance

Comment: How can I get PFFile instance

Comment: What is your data model in parse.com ?

Comment: @Wain Edited my question with data model screenshot, thanks for providing all the support, Please help me on this, I urgently need this to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your image data with:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [business objectForKey:@"aboutImage"];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        UIImage *aboutImage = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
        // use your image
    }
}];
```